# Normalizing a deeply nested JSON/Dictionary

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary, normalization

I am trying to normalize a deeply nested json/dictionary as per example below. Currently the record_path and meta are hardcoded but eventually i want to make it dynamical.

```
from pandas import json_normalize

data = {
   "test": [
       {
           "landje": "ES",
           "broodje": [
               {"coupon": "abcde", "aap": [{"type": "dirk", "dirk_code": "1234"}], "days_due": ["1"]},
               {"coupon": "zxcv", "aap": [{"type": "dirk", "dirk_code": "2345"}], "days_due": ["2"]}
           ]
       },
       {
           "landje": "FR",
           "broodje": [
               {"coupon": "ergd", "aap": [{"type": "dirk", "dirk_code": "4567"}], "days_due": ["3"]},
               {"coupon": "tygh", "aap": [{"type": "dirk", "dirk_code": "7789"}], "days_due": ["4"]}
           ]
       }
   ]
}

# Use json_normalize with meta parameter
df_nested = json_normalize(data, record_path =["test","broodje"], meta=["landje", "coupon", "type", "dirk_code","days_due"])

# Display the resulting DataFrame
print(df_nested)
```

However, i would like to look the result something similar to this, the column names are not important but i want to extract all this info:

```
  landje coupon broodje[*].aap.type test.broodje[*].aap.dirk_code test.broodje[*].days_due
0          ES                  abcde                      dirk                          1234                         1
1          ES                   zxcv                      dirk                          2345                         2
2          FR                  ergd                       dirk                          4567                         3
3          FR                   tygh                      dirk                          7789                         4
```

However, i cannot solve the problem on how to extract the meta right. Especially trying to figure out the structure to do it eventually without hardcoding it. Currently i used hardcoding to determine the necessary syntax/structure for meta. Also there needs to be some kind of concat because of the two different "landje" and "broodje". Any help is welcome and thanks in advance!

Comment: Your JSON is incorrect; the keys 'landje' and 'broodje' are repeated.

Answer (score 1):

Your dictionary is incorrect. In dicts duplicate keys are not allowed. In your dictionary the keys `landje` and `broodje` are repeated. So the correct version would be:

```
data = {
   "test": [{
       "landje": "ES",
       "broodje": [
           {
               "coupon": "abcde",
               "aap": {"type": "dirk", "dirk_code": "1234"},
               "days_due": "1"
           },
           {
               "coupon": "zxcv",
               "aap": {"type": "dirk", "dirk_code": "2345"},
               "days_due": "2"
           }
       ]},
       {"landje": "FR",
       "broodje": [
           {
               "coupon": "qwer",
               "aap": {"type": "dirk", "dirk_code": "1234"},
               "days_due": "3"
           },
           {
               "coupon": "tyui",
               "aap": {"type": "dirk", "dirk_code": "2345"},
               "days_due": "4"
           }
       ]
   }]}
```

Then use **[`json_normalize()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html)**:

```
df_nested = json_normalize(data["test"],record_path=["broodje"],meta='landje')
```

**Out**:

```
  coupon days_due aap.type aap.dirk_code landje
0  abcde        1     dirk          1234     ES
1   zxcv        2     dirk          2345     ES
2   qwer        3     dirk          1234     FR
3   tyui        4     dirk          2345     FR
```